# Is there a way to make these scaledBitmaps take up less memory so that I don't keep getting to much output process?

Tags: java, android

This is the class and the bitmaps in question are in the surface changed method. Is there a way that I can load them that will take up less memory because at the moment all I can do is load those and it uses a majority of my memory and I get a too much output process error.

```
public class Screen extends SurfaceView {
private boolean click = false;
public static boolean show;
public int numL;
private MainThread main;
private Context context;
public static int width, height;
Canvas c = new Canvas();
public boolean screenCreated = false;
public static Random rn = new Random();
public static int l = rn.nextInt(3);


public Screen(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    main = new MainThread(this);
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            if (!main.running) {
                main.running = true;
                main.start();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Screen.width = width;
            Screen.height = height;

            Bitmap bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circle);
            int h = Screen.height; // Height in pixels
            int w =Screen.width; // Width in pixels
            bgscaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bg, w, h, false);
            bg.recycle();

           Bitmap redl = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.redl);
           redlscaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(redl, w, h, false);
            redl.recycle();

            Bitmap yellowl = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yellowl);
            yellowlscaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yellowl, w, h, false);
            yellowl.recycle();

           Bitmap bluel = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bluel);
           bluelscaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bluel, w, h, false);
            bluel.recycle();

            Bitmap greenl = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.greenl);
            greenlscaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(greenl, w, h, false);
            greenl.recycle();

            screenCreated = true;
        }




        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }
    });

setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        click = false;
    }
});
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(click) return false;
        click = true;

        return false;
    }
});
```

}

```
Bitmap bgscaled;
Bitmap redlscaled;
Bitmap bluelscaled;
Bitmap greenlscaled;
Bitmap yellowlscaled;
public void render(Canvas c) {
    if (c == null || !screenCreated) return;
    if(l ==  0) {
        c.drawBitmap(greenlscaled, 0, 0, null);
    }else if(l == 1){
        c.drawBitmap(redlscaled, 0, 0, null);
    }else if(l == 2){
        c.drawBitmap(yellowlscaled, 0, 0, null);
    }else if(l == 3){
        c.drawBitmap(bluelscaled,0,0,null);
    }else{
        c.drawBitmap(bgscaled, 0,0, null);
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  A Bitmap object takes 4*width*height bytes, because its an uncompressed bitmap for use with a bitblt command to draw to the screen.  Generally the answer is not to use a bitmap when possible (use a Drawable for a solid color, for example).  If that isn't possible, use an LRUCache for the bitmaps so only a fixed amount of memory is used for bitmaps, and deal with cache misses by loading it into memory as needed.